# preventing Cross site request forgery

Tags: php, post

One of the ways to prevent CSRF is to use tokens in the forms. After going through a lot of articles i figured out that the steps are usually along these lines:

1. Generate a **token value which is encryted**, store it in a session,set the token value in a hidden field in the  form.
2. In the form processing page compare the token value in the hidden field and the session value for equality like this: $_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']

My question is **why should i encrypt the token value?** Assuming that i am using GET method and the attacker knows that i am going to use a simple integer value between lets say 1 to 1000.
If the attacker is going to use an image to forge the request, then he will have to send 1000 images to brute force the request..right? or is there any other way to do this?

Also i have read that using POST method alone is not enough to prevent CSRF requests. So My second question is that if this is true, **how can an attacker successfully create a forged request if i am using the POST method ?**

Comment: You don't need to encrypt the token, you just need to make it random, so do not use a number between 1 and 1000, generate a long token usually sha1 or md5 some random string would suffice. If you have a form on your site I can duplicate the form on my site where the 'action' for form points to your site and have javascript on my site submit the form, and it would appear as a POST request to your form.

Answer (score 0):

For an attacker using many automated processes and applications doing a 1000 brute-force requests is only a question of a few minutes.

Therefore it is good to set the token like this:

```
$token = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
```

By this You always end up with the **unique random token** while the encryption is not needed at all - it just adds more obfuscation :-). Use Your preffered crypting method, somebody uses only `sha1()` these days, some goes further. But this is not a Pentagon safezone, only a **random token** that **should not** be easy to guess doing a brute-force attacks.

Using POST method is not enough indeed - I have installed an extension to my Firefox that can pick up a URL with GET parameters and transform it into a POST request. Easy as a copy + paste + click.

Also, You do not need to set the token into a hidden field, You could also use it as a GET parameter of the form action URL while reading the token from a GET and the form data from a POST array...

Comment: Or use a Cookie, the you don't need to apply the Token on every page/link.

Comment: But those "automated processes and applications" that you said will only work on server side right? how do you make those applications send request from the victims browser?